# Add XML to mongodb with Pre-Determined JSON Schema in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xml, mongodb

I want to convert an XML file that I upload through a front end Angular application to a specific JSON Schema that is dictated in MongoDB. As of right now I have a controller set up to handle xml2js and return the strict JSON string. In Angular this is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller = "xmlCtrl">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2 class="page-header">Input File</h2>
      <input type="file" style="display: none"/>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" value="Convert" ng-click="#convert"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2 class="page-header">Output File</h2>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <input type="button" value="Download XML" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="downloadXml()" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <input type="button" value="Download CSV" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="downloadCsv()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var xmlJsonApp = angular.module('xmlJsonApp', []);

  var fs = require('fs'),
  var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile('#convert', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log('Done');
    });
});
```

JSON Schema:

```
var XmlsanitizerSchema = new Schema({
  dateTime: String,
  userLogin: String,
  campaignName: String,
  adgroupName: String,
  changes: {
    productGroup: String,
    keyword: String,
    oldBid: Number,
    newBid: Number
  }

});
```

Right now I am focusing on just the upload into the JSON Schema, but I am a little lost on how to do this.